# how do i resolve the issue of my cs50 finance not registering

Tags: python, xcode, cs50, finance

Here is the result after running the code.

INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2022 21:27:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2022 21:27:43] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2022 21:27:43] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
DEBUG: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'amaka';
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2022 21:27:47] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 403 -
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2022 21:27:48] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
"""Register user"""
if (request.method == "post"):
username = request.form.get('username')
password = request.form.get('password')
confirmation = request.form.get('confirmation')

```
    if not username:
        return apology('please enter username')
    elif not password:
        return apology('password is required!')
    elif not confirmation:
        return apology('confirmation password is required!')

    if password != confirmation:
        return apology('passwords do not match!')

    hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    try:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users(username, hash) VALUES (?,?)", username, hash)
        return redirect('/')
    except:
        return apology('username has already being registered')
else:
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what "*the issue*" is, as you haven't provided nearly enough contextual information for potential answerers to get to the bottom of the problem. Please edit your question to conform to our guidance on [ask], as well as creating a [mre].

Comment: This might happen if the form action in register.html is `/login`.